# Vue Simple Suggestion doesn't work with promisse

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await

I am trying to use the vue suggestion componente: https://github.com/KazanExpress/vue-simple-suggest/blob/master/example/src/App.vue specifically the assync  part. The documentation says I have to return a promissem but when I do, I get an error on console.log

[image: Error showed on console.log]

This is my function code:

```
  getFonts: function () {
      var filter = this.news.reference;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
          .post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_HOST}/api/get_fonts/`, {
            filter: filter,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            resolve(response.data);
          });
      });
    },
```

And this is my component:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for>Fonte</label>
                <vue-simple-suggest
                  v-model="news.reference"
                  :list="getFonts()"
                  :value-attribute="reference"
                  :styles="autoCompleteStyle"
                  :display-attribute="reference"
                  :filter-by-query="true"
                ></vue-simple-suggest>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Any ideas how I resolve that? I followed the documenation but I am really stuck

Comment: make prop called fontLists in data, then set it into `:list="fontLists"`, then call your getFonts method in beforeMount/mounted without the promise wrapping and simply set `this.fontLists = response.data`.. the hint is in the error message, it's expecting an array not a promise

Comment: Reading the documentation you can see that the example described returns a promisse, thats made me confuse. I did something close to what you suggested, but I need to call getFonts every time the v-model changes, this works like a search bar. I tried use some watch on the reference on v-model but the data keeps delayed, beeing always one search behind current one.

Comment: my bad, I didn't check [docs](https://github.com/KazanExpress/vue-simple-suggest#async-example) example, it does accept a promise but would be like `:list="getFonts"` not invoked (that would be the Function mention in the error). also you dont need wrap it simply `return axios` and change `resolve(response.data);` to `return response.data`;

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that there's a diference between "getFonts" and "getFonts()". Also, the problem with the delayed data inside de v-model persists, if the v-model var is empty and I type "test" for example, it sends "empty" to the function, and if I type another example it sends the last one, in this case "test". I don't know if I made myself clear, if you have anyidea I would love it, but anyway thank you very  much!